# How to retrieve iOS App info from another iOS App?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, mobile, package-info

so I'm trying to create plugin for Flutter, where I'll be able to use it in order to show information regarding device/app. 
I've managed to do it for `android/java` by including

```
if (call.method.equals("getPackageInfo")) {
  String packageName = call.argument("packageName"); --> being "com.example.appName"
  try {
    PackageInfo info = devMenu.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
  }
}
```

Now I'm wondering if it is possible to do the same for iOS? Code from down under is retrieving information but not for the main package `"com.example.appName"` because I didn't find any option to pass that String and get correct data.

```
if ([call.method isEqualToString:@"getPackageInfo"]) {
  result(@{
    @"appName" : [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"]
        ?: [NSNull null],
    @"packageName" : [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier] ?: [NSNull null],
    @"version" : [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]
        ?: [NSNull null],
  });
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: i do not think you can get an info.plist file from another app. This would violate Apples "sandbox" principle, where each App can only access each Apps content (there are some exceptions like shared data...but not for info.plist as far as i know)

Comment: Thanks @Chris for your time :)